# Set Wall Instance Id into Parameter Wall Id

Tags: c#, revit-api

I would like to put the wall ID's into the properties of the walls.

The Code Builds but doesn't put the wall id into the parameter wall id for all the walls.

I've tried without transactions and with. I'm under the impression it has to be carried out using them but I'm not getting the right result (or any result).

public void InsertWallID()
        {

```
        Document doc = this.ActiveUIDocument.Document; 

        FilteredElementCollector collector =    new FilteredElementCollector(doc);

        ICollection<Element> WallEls =  collector.OfClass(typeof(FamilyInstance)).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls).ToElements();


using (Transaction trans = new Transaction(doc, "Change wall parameters values"))
{
    trans.Start();

        int WallIDValue;

    foreach(Element WallEl in WallEls)
        {           
        ElementId WallId = WallEl.Id;
        WallIDValue = WallId.IntegerValue;
        if(WallEl.LookupParameter("WallID")==null)
        {


        Parameter wallparam = WallEl.LookupParameter("WallID") as Parameter;
            wallparam.Set(WallIDValue);
        }
            }
          trans.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Expected result:
Each instance has its own id in their parameters. which would let me schedule the walls and their wall ID's

Actual Result:
No change to the parameter WallID as its still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should step through your code in the debugger and watch what happens line by line. Then you would see what is going wrong: no walls are found by your filtered element collector.

Before programming anything at all, you should use [RevitLookup](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup) and other database exploration tools to ensure that you are looking for the right thing.

If you snoop a wall, you will see that it is not a `FamilyInstance` element.

There is a dedicated `Wall` class for walls.

If you just filter for `OfClass(typeof(Wall))` you will get them.

Also, the call to `ToElements` is a waste of time and memory space. Simply delete it.

I have discussed that very often on [The Building Coder](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com).

There is no need to use `ToElements` if you just want to iterate over the results of a filtered element collector.

You can iterate directly over the collector itself.

Using `ToElements` creates a copy of the information and uses time and space for no reason, cf., [FindElement and collector optimisation](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/09/findelement-and-collector-optimisation.html).